# Java creating instance of ArrayList from other class

Tags: java, object, arraylist

The situation looks like this:

First class:

```
class Something {
    List<Object> names;
    public Something(){
       this.names = new ArrayList<Object>();    
    }
}
```

Second class I tried do something like that and it is not working:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something names = new Something();
        ...
        for(Object name: names){
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

And it says that I can't iterate through "names" why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Something` does not implement `Iterable<T>`, so you cannot iterate over it directly; you must iterate over its `names` field: `for(Object name : names.names)`

Comment: Getter/setter ... better yet, let your IDE create them for you, so you may avoid carpal tunnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intend to iterate over the list *inside* your `Something` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Something something = new Something();
    // then assign something.names to something
    ...
    for (Object name: something.getNames()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So, you probably want to expose a getter and setter for the `names` list in your class:

```
class Something {
    List<Object> names;

    public Something() {
        this.names = new ArrayList<Object>();    
    }

    public List<Object> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<Object> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give fine solutions. But what if you *do* want to use just `something` in the enhanced for loop?

You have to make the class implement `Iterable`:

```
class Something implements Iterable<Object> {
```

And implement the `iterator()` method:

```
@Override public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
  return names.iterator(); // for example.
}
```

Now you can write:

```
for (Object object : something) { ... }
```

and it will be acceptable to the compiler.

But you should only do this if `Something` *is-a* Iterable of Objects, i.e. that it is intrinsically modelling something which should be iterated (e.g. it is "like a List"). Otherwise, if it merely *has-a* Iterable of Objects, stick to the other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to call your `Something` instance `names`.  `names` is a **member** of the `Something` class instance.  You are trying to iterate your `Something` class, and not `names` array inside it.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something something = new Something();
        ...
        for(Object name: something.names){
           do smth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Something` class is not a `List`. But it contains a `List`.

```
class Something {
    List<Object> names;

    public List<Object> getNames(){
       this.names = new ArrayList<Object>();    
    }

    public void setNames( List<Object> list ){
       this.names = list;    
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something somethingObj= new Something();
       List<Object> newNames = new ArrayList<>();
       newNames.add( new Object() );
       somethingObj.setNames( newNames ); 

        for(Object name: somethingObj.getNames()){
           ...
        }
    }
}
```